# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to execute a few queries to get a page of information about some images. I've written a function

```
function get_recent_highs($view_deleted_images=false)
{
    $lower = $this->database->conn->real_escape_string($this->page_size * ($this->page_number - 1));
    $query = "SELECT image_id, date_uploaded FROM `images` ORDER BY ((SELECT SUM( image_id=`images`.image_id ) FROM `image_votes` AS score) / (SELECT DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , date_uploaded ) AS diff)) DESC LIMIT " . $this->page_size . " OFFSET $lower"; //move to database class
    $result = $this->database->query($query);
    $page = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        try
        {
            array_push($page, new Image($row['image_id'], $view_deleted_images));
        }
        catch(ImageNotFoundException $e)
        {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    return $page;
}
```

that selects a page of these images based on their popularity. I've written a `Database` class that handles interactions with the database and an `Image` class that holds information about an image. When I attempt to run this I get an error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
```

`$result` is a mysqli resultset, so I'm baffled as to why this isn't working.

Comment: var_dump on $result confirms it is a mysqli result set?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

That's because there was an error in your query.  [`MySQli->query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) will return false on error.  Change it to something like::

```
$result = $this->database->query($query);
if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception("Database Error [{$this->database->errno}] {$this->database->error}");
}
```

That should throw an exception if there's an error...

Comment: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Answer (score 10):

Most likely your query failed, and the query call returned a boolean FALSE (or an error object of some sort), which you then try to use as if was a resultset object, causing the error. Try something like `var_dump($result)` to see what you really got.

Check for errors after EVERY database query call. Even if the query itself is syntactically valid, there's far too many reasons for it to fail anyways - checking for errors every time will save you a lot of grief at some point.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to miss spaces in my query and this error comes.

```
Ex: $sql= "SELECT * FROM";
$sql .= "table1";
```

Though the example might look simple, when coding complex queries, the probability for this error is high. I was missing space before word "table1".

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have already close the database connection or not.
In my case i was getting the error because the connection was close in upper line.

Comment: Please check if there is already an accepted answer to a seven(!) year old question that would tell you just the same thing