# Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121027/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object)

I have the following code:

```
$this->open_connection();
$result = $this->connection->query($this->query);           
while($this->rows[] = $result->fetch_assoc()){}                     
$result->close();
$this->close_connection();
array_pop($this->rows);
```

Running this code on localhost, does not give me any problems, I returned the values ​​of the query. But when run from the server sends me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/code..on    line 36
```

I have read several publications, but I have not managed to solve this little problem.
Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: $result is probably 'false', as the connection or the query failed. Rewrite your code by adding proper error handling...

Comment: Probably, its been answered,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121027/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object