# What is error on this code

Tags: php

**//what is error on this code**

```
<?php
$dbserver="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpwd="";
$dbname="sectinfo_aisect";

$cid= new mysqli($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpwd,$dbname);

if($cid->error){
    die("Connection Faild:". $cid->error);
}

$userName='Devendra';
$result = $cid-> query("SELECT designation, FROM user WHERE subadmin= '22' and username='$userName' ");

$row = $result-> fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['designation'];

?>
```

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in**

Comment: and the error is? Oo

Comment: Who knows. Why don't you tell us?

Comment: you mean $cid->fetch_assoc()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch\_assoc() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121027/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by editing your lines.

```
$result = $cid-> query("SELECT designation FROM user WHERE subadmin= '22' and username='".$userName."'");

$row = $result-> fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

this error is because there is a error in your query `$mysqli->query()`

> for reference - [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

To see if your queries are correct.

- Echo them directly in your html
- copy them and run them into phpmyadmin
- it will be more clear what you get output from there (error/data)

Comment: now check updated code !!

Comment: dont  pass `$result` in your fetch_assoc(), that is only required in procedural style

Answer (score 0):

Now check with this

$result = $cid -> query("SELECT designation FROM user WHERE username= '". $adminName ."'");
    if ($result) {
        $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
    echo $designation = $row['designation'];
    }