# How to display the full content of a database on clicking on 'Read More' button

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a database named ***Magazine*** and it has a table ***social_media***. The table has 5 columns namely ***ID, Headline, Author, Content Short, Content***. The ***Content*** ***Short*** column contains the shorter version of the entire article(which will be displayed in the following code) and the ***Content*** column contains the entire article(which will be displayed on clicking the Read More button). I have created a homepage where all the articles from the ***social_media*** are displayed in the ***Content_Left*** div(**NOTE:** The Content Short column is displayed and not Content). At the end of each entry from the database there is a '***Read More***' button. On clicking on that read more button I want the user to be redirected to a new page '***article.php***' where the Headline, Author and Content of the corresponding article will be displayed(The Longer version of the content and not the Content Short). How do I do it? I have created the following webpage:

```
<?php require_once('connections/connection.php'); ?>

<?php

session_start();

$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM social_media");

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#E0DDDD">
<div id="Container">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tech</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tips &amp; Tricks</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
<div id="Content_Left">
  <h1><center>Social Media</center></h1>
  <table>
   <?php
   while($records=$stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION["ID"] = $records['ID'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th><h3>".$records['Headline']."</h3></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>By <strong>".$records['Author']."</strong></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$records['Content_short']."  <a href='article.php?articleId=' " . $records['ID']. ">Read More...</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   }
   ?>
  </table>
 </div>

 <div id="Content_Center">
  <h1>Header Here </h1>
  <p>Text Goes Here!</p>
 </div>

 <div id="Content_Right">
  <h1>Header Here </h1>
  <p>Text Goes Here!</p>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="Footer">
<center>Your Copyright Message</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS file(Layout.css):

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Container {
    width: 980px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:21px;
}
#Header {
    height:120px;
    background-image:url(../Assets/Untitled-1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin-bottom:21px;
}
#NavBar {
    height:60px;
    background-color:#000000;
}

#Content {  
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#Content_Left {
    height: auto;
    width: 210px;
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    background-color: lightblue
}

#Content_Center {
    height: auto;
    padding:5px;
    width: 500px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue
}

#Content_Right {
    height: auto;
    padding:5px;
    width: 210px;
    float: right;
    background-color: lightblue
} 

#Container #Content h1 {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px;
}

#Footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And here is the CSS file(menu.css):

```
nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
nav ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:55px;
    font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:17px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background-color:#BBB5B5;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    display:block;
    color:Black;
}
```

I want to display that article in the new page but with the same background theme. Or is there any other way to display the entire article? I hope this much detail is enough. In case any more information is needed please ask.

**EDIT:** As per the suggestions of the fellow members I have edited the code. My article.php file now looks like this:

```
<?php require_once('connections/connection.php');?>

<?php
$articleId = $_GET['articleId'];

// you need to fetch only one record this time for showing only the article that wanted to be read. so use `where` condition
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM social_media WHERE id = $articleId ");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="CSS/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#E0DDDD">
<div id="Container">
<div id="Header"></div>
<div id="NavBar">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tech</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tips &amp; Tricks</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="Content">
<div id="Content_Full">
  <table>
   <?php
   while($records=$stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th><h1>".$records['Headline']."</h1></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>By <strong>".$records['Author']."</strong></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$records['Content']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   }
   ?>
  </table>
 </div>
 </div>
<div id="Footer">
<center>Your Copyright Message</center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change few thing

in php file

```
echo "<td>".$records['Content_short']."  <a href='article.php'>Read More...</a></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td>".$records['Content_short']."  <a href='article.php?articleId= " . $records['ID']. "'>Read More...</a></td>";
```

then in your **article.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['articleId'])){
    $articleId = $_GET['articleId'];
}else{
    echo "Invalid access"; die;
}

// you need to fetch only one record this time for showing only the article that wanted to be read. so use `where` condition
$stmt = $con->query("SELECT * FROM social_media WHERE id = $articleId ");
```

Follow same `html` code of your article listing page on `article.php`

Comment: I did as you said but it's giving the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object`

Comment: have you include `<?php require_once('connections/connection.php'); ?>` in your `article.php`

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I have posted the updated code and the article.php code in the above question. Please check and help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121027/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-assoc-on-a-non-object

Comment: On following the answers to the link you provided I am getting the following error: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: I noticed something. On clicking on the 'Read More' button the URL address changes to `http://localhost/Magazine/article.php?articleId=`. Now If I am not wrong there should be the ID of the article at the end of the URL(Example:  http://localhost/Magazine/article.php?articleId=1). But in my case the ID is not appearing in the URL.

Comment: check the updated code `<a href='article.php?articleId= " . $records['ID']. "'>`

Comment: Yes! It did the trick! Works perfectly now! So, what was wrong with the earlier code?

Comment: just `'` misplaced. :D

Answer (score 0):

Change your below line

```
echo "<td>".$records['Content_short']."  <a href='article.php'>Read More...</a></td>";
```

To:

```
echo "<td>".$records['Content_short']."  <a href='article.php?id=' " . $records['ID']. ">Read More...</a></td>";
```

Now you've to get details by ID and display data accordingly.